# C# powershell servermanager module couldnt be loaded

Tags: c#, powershell, windows-server, servermanager

PowerShell via C# PowerShell SDK fails to load ServerManager module on Windows Server 2019.

I am using command `Get-WindowsFeature` to find out if component is installed or not.

Exception:

```
System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The 'Get-WindowsFeature' command was found in the module 'ServerManager', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module ServerManager'.
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input)
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Pipeline.Invoke()
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.ConstructPipelineAndDoWork(Runspace rs, Boolean performSyncInvoke)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.CreateRunspaceIfNeededAndDoWork(Runspace rsToUse, Boolean isSync)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvokeHelper[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Invoke(IEnumerable input, PSInvocationSettings settings)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Invoke()
   at Class.IsWindowsFeatureInstalled(String featureName)
```

Source code:

```
    try
    {
        InitialSessionState initialSessionState = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
        initialSessionState.ImportPSModule(new string[] { "ServerManager" });

        Runspace powerShellRunscape = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initialSessionState);

        powerShellRunscape.Open();

        using PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create();

        powerShell.Runspace = powerShellRunscape;
        powerShell.AddCommand("Get-WindowsFeature");
        powerShell.AddArgument(featureName);

        powerShell.Invoke(); // exception

        // ....
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
```

Am I missing some configuration?

EDIT (.NET Framework):
Based on Mathias comment I created .NET Framework based project.

Using nuget package PowerShellStandard.Library

same source code (just older C# version).

Exception:

```
The term 'Get-WindowsFeature' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

EDIT2: .NET Framework is working, only you have to use 64bit!

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: I am using .NET 5

Comment: Well there's your problem. `ServerManager` only work in Windows PowerShell (last version of which was 5.1), which in turn only runs on .NET Framework. Target .NET Framework 4.x and use https://www.nuget.org/packages/PowerShellStandard.Library version 5.1 as your reference assembly

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks for tip, however I've got another exception which is also strange. Could you look at original edited post? Thanks

Comment: Figured out.. you have to use 64bit. If you can add answer I would accept it. Hope it hepls someone else in future